# Catkin and Eclipse - builds but indexing errors stop autocompletion

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-hydro, build, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I'm just getting started with Catkin and want to use eclipse for its autocomplete features.

The project has no problems building but still wont recognise symbols in code. It will recognise the header declarations, but not the symbols declared in those headers. Here is a screen shot:

[image: image description]

To import I followed the directions http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs and also in the ros answer linked by that page.

I've tried reindexing, opening and closing the project, deleting and reimporting the project and it is being imported perfectly (by perfect I mean drags in all includes, binaries, and compiles in eclipse). I've also closed all other C++ projects in the workspace in case they were interferring with my includes.

But I can't seem to see the errors Eclipse finds. In the project settings there is no tab for importing libraries perhaps this is an issue that eclipse cannot see these. Though they are included in the cmakelists.txt and used for the build?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/89646/catkin-and-eclipse---builds-but-indexing-errors-stop-autocompletion/) by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1493 on 2013-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

just broke the source away into hmmv4.cpp and the auto complete started working. as Colonel Klink would say: ECLIPSE!

---

Originally posted by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) with karma: 1493 on 2013-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0